# SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE P_OWNER(
     OWNERID               CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     LNAME                 VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
     FNAME                 VARCHAR2(30) NULL, 
     SSN                   CHAR(9) NULL, 
     EMAIL                 VARCHAR2(50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT            P_OWNER_PK      PRIMARY KEY(OWNERID),
     CONSTRAINT            P_OWNER_AK1     ALTERNATE KEY(SSN),
     CONSTRAINT            P_OWNER_AK2     ALTERNATE KEY(EMAIL)
     );

CREATE TABLE P_PROPERTY(
     PROPERTYID            CHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
     STREET1               VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
     STREET2               VARCHAR2(50) NULL, 
     CITY                  VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'FITCHBURG',
     STATE                 CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'MA',
     ZIP                   CHAR(10) NULL,
     SQFOOTAGE             NUMBER(5,0) NULL, 
     HAS_AC                CHAR(1) NULL,
     ISHOUSE               CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT            P_PROPERTY_PK              PRIMARY KEY(PROPERTYID),
     CONSTRAINT            P_PROPERTY_ADDRESS_AK1     ALTERNATE KEY(CITY, STATE, STREET1, STREET2, ZIP)
     );





Error at Command Line:8 Column:57
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: the error itself is self-explanatory

Comment: @Abu That error doesn't always mean that you forgot to close your parenthesis so a lot of the time, it's not..

Comment: Are you trying to create the tables at the same time?  Try running one create table statement at a time.

Comment: `ALTERNATE KEY`? Never seen that before.

Answer (score 2):

You want a Unique Key instead of Alternate

```
   CREATE TABLE P_OWNER(
 OWNERID               CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 LNAME                 VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
 FNAME                 VARCHAR2(30) NULL, 
 SSN                   CHAR(9) NULL, 
 EMAIL                 VARCHAR2(50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT            P_OWNER_PK      PRIMARY KEY(OWNERID),
 CONSTRAINT            P_OWNER_AK1     UNIQUE(SSN),
 CONSTRAINT            P_OWNER_AK2     UNIQUE(EMAIL)
 );


 CREATE TABLE P_PROPERTY(
 PROPERTYID            CHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
 STREET1               VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
 STREET2               VARCHAR2(50) NULL, 
 CITY                  VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'FITCHBURG',
 STATE                 CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'MA',
 ZIP                   CHAR(10) NULL,
 SQFOOTAGE             NUMBER(5,0) NULL, 
 HAS_AC                CHAR(1) NULL,
 ISHOUSE               CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT            P_PROPERTY_PK              PRIMARY KEY(PROPERTYID),
 CONSTRAINT            P_PROPERTY_ADDRESS_AK1     UNIQUE(CITY, STATE, STREET1, STREET2, ZIP)
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with `ALTERNATE KEY` try with  `UNIQUE`

```
CREATE TABLE P_OWNER(
     OWNERID               CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     LNAME                 VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
     FNAME                 VARCHAR2(30) NULL, 
     SSN                   CHAR(9) NULL, 
     EMAIL                 VARCHAR2(50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT            P_OWNER_PK      PRIMARY KEY(OWNERID),
     CONSTRAINT            P_OWNER_AK1     UNIQUE (SSN),
     CONSTRAINT            P_OWNER_AK2     UNIQUE (EMAIL)
     );

CREATE TABLE P_PROPERTY(
     PROPERTYID            CHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
     STREET1               VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
     STREET2               VARCHAR2(50) NULL, 
     CITY                  VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'FITCHBURG',
     STATE                 CHAR(2) DEFAULT 'MA',
     ZIP                   CHAR(10) NULL,
     SQFOOTAGE             NUMBER(5,0) NULL, 
     HAS_AC                CHAR(1) NULL,
     ISHOUSE               CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT            P_PROPERTY_PK              PRIMARY KEY(PROPERTYID),
     CONSTRAINT            P_PROPERTY_ADDRESS_AK1     UNIQUE(CITY, STATE, STREET1, STREET2, ZIP)
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

An `alternate key (or secondary key)` is any candidate key which is not selected to be the primary key (PK). You cant create an alternate key in Oracle, its just conceptual.